# Keeping information linked to a non signed in user un rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have a rails application with devise. When the user is signed in (`user_signed_in?`), I can access it and retrieve information for it (eg `current_user.last_search`). But I would also like a way to save some information linked to the session, such as the last search the user made.

Now, I have code like this:

```
<% if user_signed_in %>
  <%= current_user.last_search %>
<% else %>
  <%= get_last_seach # some method to get the last search when user is not signed in %>
```

It's too verbose. And I need to do that in a lot of places, and with other variables than `last_search`.

I would like to do something like this instead:

```
<%= my_current_user.last_search %>
```

Where `my_current_user` is the Devise current_user when the user is logged in, else it's a User linked to the current session (via cookies) with the information available.

`my_current_user` would behave like that:

```
# user starts new session on the website
user_signed_in? # false
my_current_user # Object User
my_current_user.last_search # ''

#user searches "pancakes"
user_signed_in? # false
my_current_user # Object User
my_current_user.last_search # 'pankakes'

#user logs in
user_signed_in? # true
my_current_user # Object User
my_current_user.last_search # 'pankakes'

#user logs off
user_signed_in? # false
my_current_user # Object User
my_current_user.last_search # 'pankakes' or '', I don't really mind here
```

Is this a good aproach ? What would you suggest ?
If it is a good idea, how to implement it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a helper method in an application helper like this:

```
def last_search
  user_signed_in? ? current_user.last_search : session[:last_search]
end
```

and call it from your controllers.

Unless you need to remember user's last search after logging out and then logging in again, you may always keep the search in session for all users (regardless they are logged in or not).

Comment: What if I want to access it from both controllers and views ?

Comment: You may include the application helper in the controller. If you only need it in the controller, add it to your base controller class.

Comment: It looks like the "rails way". But it feels wierd to access the name of the user with `current_user.name`, and the last search of the **same** user with `last_search`.